# How to neutralize strong fragrance from handwash?

Tags: smell

This is a weird question but I recently bought Mrs. Meyers Lavender hand soap in bulk but it has extremely strong scent and whenever I wash my hands, I get nauseous.

I am considering buying another hand wash but wanted to check if you can neutralize or reduce the fragrance in liquid products like hand wash, body wash etc?

Comment: Can't you just put a very small amount on your hand?

Comment: No, the fragrance is very concentrated.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the below will do the trick

Vinegar and water mix.

Lemon juice.

Baking soda rub, then rinse

Toothpaste, then rinse

Rub hands in coffee grounds, rinse

use salt with soap when you wash, after lathering, scrub hands with salt, rinse

Comment: I wash my hands pretty frequently so doing these again and again is pretty disruptive. However, I am going to try to do the following: 1. Put the handwash bottle in sunlight for a few hours 2. Put coffee beans in my hand wash bottle. Will update!

Answer (score 1):

First line of defense is of course: use less of it, lower the water temperature und use more water to dilute it.

---

The fragrance is usually from mostly quite [volatile essential oils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender_oil) and similar components.

Having bought this stuff in bulk lends to experimentation:

Put at first a limited, small amount of the liquid soap into a heat-proof container and that into a kettle or pot of water you bring to boil. The essential oils and the water in the liquid will evaporate to a degree.

To prevent the mass getting ever more viscous and hard, stir it and add occasionally a little bit of distilled water to keep it at roughly the same level of liquidity. After quite a short while the smell should be gone from the liquid. But of course its now in the air around your oven/boiler, so do that only in well ventilated places!

Try the result out afterwards in small amounts. I do not know that brand, and maybe God doesn't know what else they put into that stuff. There may be unwanted reaction products occuring or accumulating? Re-check the label of ingredients before attempting this. Treat any additive apart from ['detergent'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detergent) that's listed on the box with the utmost suspicion and look its properties up!

If it was just ordinary soap with "smell", you're good to try it out. With significantly less smell.

If that worked out for you, convert the rest into tolerable soap.

Answer (score 0):

Wash your hands with soap and cold water. Always use cold water for this, as hot water can dilate your skin's pores and let the odor causing oils and dirt penetrate further. Create a nice lather with the soap and scrub your hands together thoroughly before rinsing them with cold water. If this doesn't work, then try to neutralize the odor on your hands with lemon or lime juice.

Or you can use some salt as it removes odor from your hands gently and effectively. Simply pour a small amount of salt into your hands, moisten them a bit so that the salt clings on properly and rub them together. When done, rinse the salt away under running water and dry your hands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, that it 100% help, but try to use after this soap another soap, which named "endless". It made from the metal and usually used for remove the smell of the fish, onion etc.
Example from Aliexpress - [LINK](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Stainless-Steel-Soap-Oval-Shape-Deodorize-Smell-From-Hands-Retail-Magic-Eliminating-Odor-Kitchen-Bar/32904807556.html?spm=a2g0v.10010108.1000001.7.10975454RbjLlx)
[image]